# how to implement TryGetValue in boost::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-unordered

In `C#` i like `TryGetValue` method of `Dictionary` because it allows me in one call determine if dictionary contains key and receive value if so:

```
Instrument instrument;
if (isinId2Instrument.TryGetValue(isin_id, out instrument))
{
    // key exist, instrument contains value
} else {
    // key doesn't exist
}
```

How should I do the same thing with `boost::unordered_map`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`boost::unordered_map::find()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html#idp61745856-bb):

```
boost::unordered_map<std::string, int>::iterator i = m.find("hello");
if (i != m.end())
{
    std::cout << i->first << "=" << i->second << "\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Not found\n";
}
```

Comment: just to doublecheck `m.find` will spent `log N` not `N`??

Comment: @javapowered An unordered_map<> is a hash table. The performance of a hash table can be anywhere between O(1) and O(n) depending on the hashing function and the distribution of your keys.  If you want O(log n) then use std::map<>.

Comment: @javapowered The code above works for std::map<> also.  Just change boost::unordered_map<> to std::map<>.